# hive combing array<string> to one string

Tags: sql, arrays, string, hive

I have a HIVE table as following:

```
id string

first_name array < string >

last_name array < string >
```

**e.g.**

```
id, first_name, last_name


1,   [A,B],     [C,D,E]

2,   [A],       [C,D]
```

How can I write a query to convert both first_name and last_name to string, as follows?

```
id, first_name, last_name

1,   A_B,       C_D_E

2,   A,         C_D
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat_ws` which takes accepts an `array` as input.

```
select id,concat_ws('_',first_name),concat_ws('_',last_name)
from tbl
```